# mansory + infinitescroll loading

Tags: infinite-scroll

I have this code: mansory + infinite scroll jquery plugin to show a number of box.
but when I open my page, the loading of next content start when I scroll the page not at the end of it. what I wrong?

> ```
>         $container.infinitescroll({
>             navSelector  : '#page-nav',    // selector for the paged navigation 
>             nextSelector : '#page-nav a',  // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
>             itemSelector : '.box',     // selector for all items you'll retrieve
>
>             // enable debug messaging ( to console.log )
>             loading: {
>                 finishedMsg: 'Pagine da caricare terminate.',
>                 img: 'http://i.imgur.com/6RMhx.gif'
>                }
>               },
>             // trigger Masonry as a callback
>             function( newElements ) {
>                // hide new items while they are loading
>               var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });
>               // ensure that images load before adding to masonry layout
>               $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
>                 // show elems now they're ready
>                 $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
>                 $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true ); 
>               });
>              }
>           );
> ```

Answer (score 0):

`$container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true );`   Should be changed to
`$container.append( $newElems ).masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true );` 
Means... item should be added to container first.